# Создание in-memory базы данных (H2) для unit тестов. Проблема с повторной инициализацией базы в процессе выполнения тестов

Tags: java, база-данных, h2

Пишу Unit тесты для своего учебного проекта. Перед каждый тестом поднимаю in-memory H2 базу. Часть тестов проходят успешно, а тесты связанные с изменением данных в БД фэйлятся. Ниже код моего коннектора к БД:

```
public class H2ConnectionSupplier implements Connector{

    private final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from '~/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/" +
            "consoles/db/09fd9eba-5ed4-4312-89fc-e3e185dc7ba6/console.sql'";
    private final String DB_USER = "sa";
    private final String DB_PASSWORD = "";

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException("No connection with H2 Data Base");
        }
    }
}
```

Также привожу код своего репозитория и тестового класса:

```
public class MusclesGroupRepositoryImp implements Repository<MusclesGroup, Long> {

    private final static String INSERT = "INSERT INTO muscles_group (muscles_group_name) VALUES (?)";
    private final static String SELECT = "SELECT * FROM muscles_group WHERE id = ?";
    private final static String SELECT_ALL = "SELECT * FROM muscles_group";
    private final static String DELETE = "DELETE FROM muscles_group WHERE id = ?";
    private final static String UPDATE = "UPDATE muscles_group SET muscles_group_name = ?" + " WHERE id = ?";
    private Connector connector;

    public MusclesGroupRepositoryImp(Connector connector) {
        this.connector = connector;
    }

    @Override
    public MusclesGroup findById(Long id) throws TrainingAppRepositoryException {
        MusclesGroup musclesGroup = new MusclesGroup();
        try(Connection connection = connector.getConnection()) {
            try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
                preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
                preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    musclesGroup.setId(resultSet.getLong(1));
                    musclesGroup.setMusclesGroupName(resultSet.getString(2));
                }
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                connection.rollback();
                throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while trying to find exercise id = " + id);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while trying to find exercise id = " + id);
        }
        return musclesGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MusclesGroup> findAll() throws SQLException {
        List<MusclesGroup>list = new ArrayList<>();
        try(Connection connection = connector.getConnection()) {
            try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_ALL, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
                preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    MusclesGroup musclesGroup = new MusclesGroup();
                    musclesGroup.setId(resultSet.getLong(1));
                    musclesGroup.setMusclesGroupName(resultSet.getString(2));
                    list.add(musclesGroup);
                }
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                connection.rollback();
                throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while trying to find all " + MusclesGroup.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while trying to find all " + MusclesGroup.class.getSimpleName());
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Long id) throws SQLException {
        try(Connection connection = connector.getConnection()) {
            try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(DELETE)) {
                preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                connection.rollback();
                throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while removing muscle group id = " + id);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while removing muscle group id = " + id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MusclesGroup save(MusclesGroup musclesGroup) throws SQLException {
        try(Connection connection = connector.getConnection()) {
            try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, musclesGroup.getMusclesGroupName());
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                connection.rollback();
                throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while saving muscle group - " + musclesGroup.getMusclesGroupName());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new TrainingAppRepositoryException("Error while saving muscle group - " + musclesGroup.getMusclesGroupName());
        }
        return musclesGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(MusclesGroup model, Long id) throws SQLException {
        try(Connection connection = connector.getConnection()) {
            try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE)) {
                preparedStatement.setLong(2, id);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, model.getMusclesGroupName());
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                connection.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                connection.rollback();
                e.getCause();
                e.getMessage();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
}
```

Тесты:

```
public class MuscleGroupRepositoryImplTest {

    private Connector connector = new H2ConnectionSupplier();
    private MusclesGroupRepositoryImp musclesGroupRepositoryImp = new MusclesGroupRepositoryImp(connector);


    @SneakyThrows
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(longs = {1})
    @DisplayName("findById method test")
    void findByIdTest(Long id) {
        MusclesGroup musclesGroup = musclesGroupRepositoryImp.findById(id);
        assertNotNull(musclesGroup);
        assertAll("Проверка полей объекта",
                () -> assertEquals(1L, musclesGroup.getId()),
                () -> assertEquals("Грудь", musclesGroup.getMusclesGroupName())
                );
    }

    @DisplayName("save method test")
    @Test
    void saveTest() throws SQLException {
        MusclesGroup musclesGroup = new MusclesGroup();
        musclesGroup.setMusclesGroupName("Икры");
        assertNotNull(musclesGroupRepositoryImp.save(musclesGroup));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(longs = {1})
    @DisplayName("update method test")
    void updateTest(Long id) {
        MusclesGroup musclesGroup1 = new MusclesGroup(1L, "Грудь");
        MusclesGroup musclesGroup = new MusclesGroup();
        musclesGroup.setMusclesGroupName("Руки");
        musclesGroupRepositoryImp.update(musclesGroup, id);
        String actual = musclesGroupRepositoryImp.findById(id).getMusclesGroupName();
        assertNotNull(musclesGroup);
        assertNotEquals(musclesGroup1.getMusclesGroupName(), actual);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(longs = {2})
    @DisplayName("remove method test")
    void removeTest(Long id) {
        musclesGroupRepositoryImp.remove(id);
        assertNull(musclesGroupRepositoryImp.findById(id));
    }

    @DisplayName("findAll method test")
    @Test
    void findAllTest() throws SQLException {
        List<MusclesGroup> musclesGroupList = musclesGroupRepositoryImp.findAll();
        assertNotNull(musclesGroupList);
        assertAll("Проверка полученных объектов из БД",
                () -> assertEquals(new MusclesGroup(1L, "Грудь").toString(), musclesGroupList.get(0).toString()),
                () -> assertEquals(new MusclesGroup(2L, "Спина").toString(), musclesGroupList.get(1).toString()),
                () -> assertEquals(new MusclesGroup(3L, "Ноги").toString(), musclesGroupList.get(2).toString()),
                () -> assertEquals(new MusclesGroup(4L, "Плечи").toString(), musclesGroupList.get(3).toString()),
                () -> assertEquals(new MusclesGroup(5L, "Бицепс").toString(), musclesGroupList.get(4).toString()),
                () -> assertEquals(new MusclesGroup(6L, "Пресс").toString(), musclesGroupList.get(5).toString())
                );
    }
}
```

В тестах update и remove, при повторном обращении к базе (например, вызов метода `musclesGroupRepositoryImp.findById(id)`, чтобы убедиться в том, что данные изменены / удалены), возвращаются исходные значение записей БД, а не обновленные после вызова соответствующих методов.

Я понимаю, что проблема заключается как раз в объекте `musclesGroupRepositoryImp` и именно повторный вызов метода через этот инстанс поднимает новую БД. Но не могу пока придумать как по-другому организовать создание in memory БД. В документации по H2 и иных ресурсах найти решение не удалось.

На всякий случай также привожу свой SQL скрипт:

```
create schema training_app;


create table muscles_group (
                               id INT primary key auto_increment not null,
                               muscles_group_name VARCHAR(500) not null,
                               create_date TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
                               update_date TIMESTAMP default now() on update now() not null
);

create table muscles_subgroup (
                                  id INT primary key auto_increment not null,
                                  muscles_group_id INT not null,
                                  muscles_subgroup_name VARCHAR(500) not null ,
                                  create_date TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null ,
                                  update_date TIMESTAMP default now() on update now() not null ,
                                  foreign key (muscles_group_id) references muscles_group(id)
);


insert into muscles_group (muscles_group_name) values
('Грудь'),
('Спина'),
('Ноги'),
('Плечи'),
('Бицепс'),
('Пресс');
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема действительно возникает из-за того, что используется БД в памяти в режиме, когда закрытие последнего соединения уничтожает БД.

Вот что говорит [документация](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases):

> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost.

Исправить это можно используя дополнительный параметр в jdbc URL, описанный там же, а именно `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`. Значение `-1` говорит, что БД не будет уничтожаться пока не остановится JVM.

Это правда приведет к другой проблеме, а именно к тому, как вы используете параметр `INIT` в jdbc URL. Он указывает скрипт, который выполняется при установлении соединения к БД. Сейчас каждое соединение работает со свой копией базы созданной с нуля. После того, как будет добавлен `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` и работа с БД будет вестись, так как это обычно происходит в реальности (т.е. закрытие соединения не будет убивать БД), то при повторном открытии соединения возникнут ошибки, что объекты которые пробует создать `INIT` скрипт уже существуют.

Проблема в том, что параметр `INIT` не годится для этой задачи. Нужно, чтобы инициализация делалась один раз на тест, а не при каждом соединении. То есть нужно, чтобы каждый тест перед запуском инициализировал БД и приводил ее к изначальному состоянию.

Вариантов как это сделать много.

Один вариант, это перед каждым тестом (в `@BeforeEach`) выполнять скрипт, который почистит БД:

```
RunScript.execute(conn, new FileReader("~/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/" +
            "consoles/db/09fd9eba-5ed4-4312-89fc-e3e185dc7ba6/console.sql"));
```

Чтобы он нормально работал при повторных запусках, нужно вначале добавить:

```
DROP ALL OBJECTS;
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Решил вопрос, но немного другим путём.
Проблема в большей степени была в организации методов репозитория. Вместо создания соединения при обращении к методу, как в этом куске кода:
`@Override
    public void remove(Long id) throws SQLException {
        try(Connection connection = connector.getConnection())`
Я вынес отдельное поле `connection` для всех методов и этого сработало. В тестах накатываю отдельную базу для каждого тестового метода.

Comment: Для тестов такое решение может и сгодится, но для прод кода - нет. Ведь в таком варианте репозиторий постоянно держит открытое соединение к БД (и именно это не дает данным умереть), даже когда оно не нужно. Как только это исправите, то тесты сразу сломаются. Либо придется делать разную логику управления временем жизни соединения к БД для тестов и прода, что плохо, т.к. чем больше расхождений между тем как работает в тестах и на проде - тем меньше пользы от тестов. Так что все же предпочтительней, чтоб соединение  закрывалось после выполнения запроса, но при этом данные из БД не удалялись.

Answer (score 0):

для инициализации БД в тестах ты можешь использовать аннотацию `@Before` либо `@BeforeAll`.

`@Before` - Создаст единую копию локальной БД перед всеми тестами.
`@BeforeAll` - Будет создавать новую копию БД перед каждым запуском нового теста.

Пример:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        connector = new H2ConnectionSupplier();
        musclesGroupRepositoryImp = new MusclesGroupRepositoryImp(connector);
    }
```

Либо:

```
    @BeforeAll
    public void setUp() {
        connector = new H2ConnectionSupplier();
        musclesGroupRepositoryImp = new MusclesGroupRepositoryImp(connector);
    }
```

Comment: Этот ответ неправильный. Даже если так сделать все равно при каждом новом соединении будет создаваться новая БД. А соединения создаются при вызовах методов в `MusclesGroupRepositoryImp`.